# Unable to start KDE 5 after installing from EPEL on CentOS7

Tags: centos, kde5

#### Context:

I am stumped on how to get KDE 5 started after installing the kf5-plasma & Dependencies downloaded from EPEL. I am trying to get KDE 5 started after installing the RPMs below using yum. I have installed this on CentOS 7.5 after a minimal install. I am not able to get a `systemctl set-default graphical.target` to work with it either.

#### Question:

Is there any detailed documentation to getting this started? or how to start it manually?

#### Trying to run manually:

```
[root@server kf5]# pwd
/usr/libexec/kf5/
[root@server kf5]# ./kiod5
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: could not connect to display
Could not connect to any X display
```

#### Yum history:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Transaction ID : 3
Begin time     : Thu Sep 13 09:14:26 2018
Begin rpmdb    : 301:fda52870e6287498622078fa9e0c69350f766746
End time       :            09:15:38 2018 (72 seconds)
End rpmdb      : 520:7ec9fba2c85c5fa8c6c907cdcb0eccc5a21b0078
User           : root <root>
Return-Code    : Success
Command Line   : install kf5-plasma
Transaction performed with:
    Installed     rpm-4.11.3-32.el7.x86_64                      @anaconda                                                                                                                                                                    
    Installed     yum-3.4.3-158.el7.centos.noarch               @anaconda                                                                                                                                                                    
    Installed     yum-metadata-parser-1.1.4-10.el7.x86_64       @anaconda                                                                                                                                                                    
    Updated       yum-plugin-fastestmirror-1.1.31-45.el7.noarch @anaconda                                                                                                                                                                    
Packages Altered:                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    Dep-Install adwaita-cursor-theme-3.26.0-1.el7.noarch              @base                                                                                                                                                                  
    Dep-Install avahi-libs-0.6.31-19.el7.x86_64                       @base                                                                                                                                                                  
    Dep-Install boost-system-1.53.0-27.el7.x86_64                     @base                                                                                                                                                                  
    Dep-Install boost-thread-1.53.0-27.el7.x86_64                     @base                                                                                                                                                                  
    Dep-Install cairo-1.14.8-2.el7.x86_64                             @base                                                                                                                                                                  
    Dep-Install cdparanoia-libs-10.2-17.el7.x86_64                    @base                                                                                                                                                                  
    Dep-Install cups-libs-1:1.6.3-35.el7.x86_64                       @base                                                                                                                                                                  
    Dep-Install dbusmenu-qt5-0.9.3-0.1.20150604.el7.x86_64            @epel                                                                                                                                                                  
    Dep-Install device-mapper-multipath-0.4.9-119.el7_5.1.x86_64      @updates                                                                                                                                                               
    Dep-Install device-mapper-multipath-libs-0.4.9-119.el7_5.1.x86_64 @updates                                                                                                                                                               
    Dep-Install docbook-dtds-1.0-60.el7.noarch                        @base                                                                                                                                                                  
    Dep-Install docbook-style-xsl-1.78.1-3.el7.noarch                 @base                                                                                                                                                                  
    Dep-Install dosfstools-3.0.20-9.el7.x86_64                        @base                                                                                                                                                                  
    Dep-Install flac-libs-1.3.0-5.el7_1.x86_64                        @base
    Dep-Install fontconfig-2.10.95-11.el7.x86_64                      @base
    Dep-Install fontpackages-filesystem-1.44-8.el7.noarch             @base
    Dep-Install gamin-0.1.10-16.el7.x86_64                            @base
    Dep-Install gdisk-0.8.6-5.el7.x86_64                              @base
    Dep-Install gdk-pixbuf2-2.36.5-1.el7.x86_64                       @base
    Dep-Install glib-networking-2.50.0-1.el7.x86_64                   @base
    Dep-Install glx-utils-8.2.0-3.el7.x86_64                          @base
    Dep-Install gnutls-3.3.26-9.el7.x86_64                            @base
    Dep-Install graphite2-1.3.10-1.el7_3.x86_64                       @base
    Dep-Install gsettings-desktop-schemas-3.24.1-2.el7_5.x86_64       @updates
    Dep-Install gsm-1.0.13-11.el7.x86_64                              @base
    Dep-Install gstreamer1-1.10.4-2.el7.x86_64                        @base
    Dep-Install gstreamer1-plugins-base-1.10.4-1.el7.x86_64           @base
    Dep-Install gstreamer1-plugins-good-1.10.4-2.el7.x86_64           @base
    Dep-Install harfbuzz-1.3.2-1.el7.x86_64                           @base
    Dep-Install hicolor-icon-theme-0.12-7.el7.noarch                  @base
    Dep-Install hunspell-1.3.2-15.el7.x86_64                          @base
    Dep-Install hunspell-en-US-0.20121024-6.el7.noarch                @base
    Dep-Install iso-codes-3.46-2.el7.noarch                           @base
    Dep-Install jasper-libs-1.900.1-31.el7.x86_64                     @base
    Dep-Install jbigkit-libs-2.0-11.el7.x86_64                        @base
    Dep-Install kde-filesystem-4-47.el7.x86_64                        @base
    Dep-Install kde-settings-19-23.7.el7.centos.noarch                @base
    Dep-Install kf5-attica-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                        @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-filesystem-5.47.0-1.el7.x86_64                    @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-kactivities-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                   @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-karchive-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                      @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-kauth-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                         @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-kcodecs-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                       @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-kcompletion-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                   @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-kconfig-core-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                  @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-kconfig-gui-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                   @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-kconfigwidgets-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-kcoreaddons-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                   @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-kcrash-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                        @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-kdbusaddons-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                   @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-kdeclarative-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                  @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-kdoctools-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                     @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-kglobalaccel-5.47.0-3.el7.x86_64                  @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-kglobalaccel-libs-5.47.0-3.el7.x86_64             @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-kguiaddons-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                    @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-ki18n-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                         @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-kiconthemes-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                   @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-kinit-5.47.0-1.el7.x86_64                         @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-kio-core-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                      @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-kio-core-libs-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                 @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-kio-doc-5.47.0-2.el7.noarch                       @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-kio-ntlm-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                      @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-kio-widgets-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                   @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-kio-widgets-libs-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64              @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-kitemviews-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                    @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-kjobwidgets-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                   @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-knotifications-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-kpackage-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                      @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-kservice-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                      @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-ktextwidgets-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                  @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-kwallet-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                       @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-kwallet-libs-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                  @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-kwidgetsaddons-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-kwindowsystem-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                 @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-kxmlgui-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                       @epel
    Install     kf5-plasma-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                        @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-solid-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                         @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-sonnet-core-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                   @epel
    Dep-Install kf5-sonnet-ui-5.47.0-2.el7.x86_64                     @epel
    Updated     kpartx-0.4.9-119.el7.x86_64                           @anaconda
    Update             0.4.9-119.el7_5.1.x86_64                       @updates
    Dep-Install libICE-1.0.9-9.el7.x86_64                             @base
    Dep-Install libSM-1.2.2-2.el7.x86_64                              @base
    Dep-Install libX11-1.6.5-1.el7.x86_64                             @base
    Dep-Install libX11-common-1.6.5-1.el7.noarch                      @base
    Dep-Install libXau-1.0.8-2.1.el7.x86_64                           @base
    Dep-Install libXcursor-1.1.14-8.el7.x86_64                        @base
    Dep-Install libXdamage-1.1.4-4.1.el7.x86_64                       @base
    Dep-Install libXext-1.3.3-3.el7.x86_64                            @base
    Dep-Install libXfixes-5.0.3-1.el7.x86_64                          @base
    Dep-Install libXft-2.3.2-2.el7.x86_64                             @base
    Dep-Install libXi-1.7.9-1.el7.x86_64                              @base
    Dep-Install libXinerama-1.1.3-2.1.el7.x86_64                      @base
    Dep-Install libXrandr-1.5.1-2.el7.x86_64                          @base
    Dep-Install libXrender-0.9.10-1.el7.x86_64                        @base
    Dep-Install libXtst-1.2.3-1.el7.x86_64                            @base
    Dep-Install libXv-1.0.11-1.el7.x86_64                             @base
    Dep-Install libXxf86vm-1.1.4-1.el7.x86_64                         @base
    Dep-Install libasyncns-0.8-7.el7.x86_64                           @base
    Dep-Install libatasmart-0.19-6.el7.x86_64                         @base
    Dep-Install libavc1394-0.5.3-14.el7.x86_64                        @base
    Dep-Install libblockdev-2.12-3.el7.x86_64                         @base
    Dep-Install libblockdev-crypto-2.12-3.el7.x86_64                  @base
    Dep-Install libblockdev-fs-2.12-3.el7.x86_64                      @base
    Dep-Install libblockdev-loop-2.12-3.el7.x86_64                    @base
    Dep-Install libblockdev-mdraid-2.12-3.el7.x86_64                  @base
    Dep-Install libblockdev-part-2.12-3.el7.x86_64                    @base
    Dep-Install libblockdev-swap-2.12-3.el7.x86_64                    @base
    Dep-Install libblockdev-utils-2.12-3.el7.x86_64                   @base
    Dep-Install libbytesize-1.2-1.el7.x86_64                          @base
    Dep-Install libdv-1.0.0-17.el7.x86_64                             @base
    Dep-Install libepoxy-1.3.1-2.el7_5.x86_64                         @updates
    Dep-Install libgudev1-219-57.el7_5.1.x86_64                       @updates
    Dep-Install libicu-50.1.2-15.el7.x86_64                           @base
    Dep-Install libiec61883-1.2.0-10.el7.x86_64                       @base
    Dep-Install libimobiledevice-1.2.0-1.el7.x86_64                   @base
    Dep-Install libjpeg-turbo-1.2.90-5.el7.x86_64                     @base
    Dep-Install libmng-1.0.10-14.el7.x86_64                           @base
    Dep-Install libmodman-2.0.1-8.el7.x86_64                          @base
    Dep-Install libogg-2:1.3.0-7.el7.x86_64                           @base
    Dep-Install libplist-1.12-3.el7.x86_64                            @base
    Dep-Install libpng-2:1.5.13-7.el7_2.x86_64                        @base
    Dep-Install libproxy-0.4.11-11.el7.x86_64                         @base
    Dep-Install librados2-1:0.94.5-2.el7.x86_64                       @base
    Dep-Install libraw1394-2.1.0-2.el7.x86_64                         @base
    Dep-Install libreport-filesystem-2.1.11-40.el7.centos.x86_64      @base
    Dep-Install libshout-2.2.2-11.el7.x86_64                          @base
    Dep-Install libsndfile-1.0.25-10.el7.x86_64                       @base
    Dep-Install libsoup-2.56.0-6.el7.x86_64                           @base
    Dep-Install libthai-0.1.14-9.el7.x86_64                           @base
    Dep-Install libtheora-1:1.1.1-8.el7.x86_64                        @base
    Dep-Install libtiff-4.0.3-27.el7_3.x86_64                         @base
    Dep-Install libudisks2-2.7.3-6.el7.x86_64                         @base
    Dep-Install libusbmuxd-1.0.10-5.el7.x86_64                        @base
    Dep-Install libusbx-1.0.21-1.el7.x86_64                           @base
    Dep-Install libv4l-0.9.5-4.el7.x86_64                             @base
    Dep-Install libvisual-0.4.0-16.el7.x86_64                         @base
    Dep-Install libvorbis-1:1.3.3-8.el7.1.x86_64                      @updates
    Dep-Install libvpx-1.3.0-5.el7_0.x86_64                           @base
    Dep-Install libwayland-client-1.14.0-2.el7.x86_64                 @base
    Dep-Install libwayland-server-1.14.0-2.el7.x86_64                 @base
    Dep-Install libxcb-1.12-1.el7.x86_64                              @base
    Dep-Install libxshmfence-1.2-1.el7.x86_64                         @base
    Dep-Install libxslt-1.1.28-5.el7.x86_64                           @base
    Dep-Install lyx-fonts-2.2.3-1.el7.noarch                          @epel
    Dep-Install mdadm-4.0-13.el7.x86_64                               @base
    Dep-Install media-player-info-17-4.el7.noarch                     @base
    Dep-Install mesa-libEGL-17.2.3-8.20171019.el7.x86_64              @base
    Dep-Install mesa-libGL-17.2.3-8.20171019.el7.x86_64               @base
    Dep-Install mesa-libgbm-17.2.3-8.20171019.el7.x86_64              @base
    Dep-Install mesa-libglapi-17.2.3-8.20171019.el7.x86_64            @base
    Dep-Install mpfr-3.1.1-4.el7.x86_64                               @base
    Dep-Install nettle-2.7.1-8.el7.x86_64                             @base
    Dep-Install opus-1.0.2-6.el7.x86_64                               @base
    Dep-Install orc-0.4.26-1.el7.x86_64                               @base
    Dep-Install pango-1.40.4-1.el7.x86_64                             @base
    Dep-Install pcre2-utf16-10.23-2.el7.x86_64                        @base
    Dep-Install perl-4:5.16.3-292.el7.x86_64                          @base
    Dep-Install perl-Carp-1.26-244.el7.noarch                         @base
    Dep-Install perl-Encode-2.51-7.el7.x86_64                         @base
    Dep-Install perl-Exporter-5.68-3.el7.noarch                       @base
    Dep-Install perl-File-Path-2.09-2.el7.noarch                      @base
    Dep-Install perl-File-Temp-0.23.01-3.el7.noarch                   @base
    Dep-Install perl-Filter-1.49-3.el7.x86_64                         @base
    Dep-Install perl-Getopt-Long-2.40-3.el7.noarch                    @base
    Dep-Install perl-HTTP-Tiny-0.033-3.el7.noarch                     @base
    Dep-Install perl-PathTools-3.40-5.el7.x86_64                      @base
    Dep-Install perl-Pod-Escapes-1:1.04-292.el7.noarch                @base
    Dep-Install perl-Pod-Perldoc-3.20-4.el7.noarch                    @base
    Dep-Install perl-Pod-Simple-1:3.28-4.el7.noarch                   @base
    Dep-Install perl-Pod-Usage-1.63-3.el7.noarch                      @base
    Dep-Install perl-Scalar-List-Utils-1.27-248.el7.x86_64            @base
    Dep-Install perl-Socket-2.010-4.el7.x86_64                        @base
    Dep-Install perl-Storable-2.45-3.el7.x86_64                       @base
    Dep-Install perl-Text-ParseWords-3.29-4.el7.noarch                @base
    Dep-Install perl-Time-HiRes-4:1.9725-3.el7.x86_64                 @base
    Dep-Install perl-Time-Local-1.2300-2.el7.noarch                   @base
    Dep-Install perl-constant-1.27-2.el7.noarch                       @base
    Dep-Install perl-libs-4:5.16.3-292.el7.x86_64                     @base
    Dep-Install perl-macros-4:5.16.3-292.el7.x86_64                   @base
    Dep-Install perl-parent-1:0.225-244.el7.noarch                    @base
    Dep-Install perl-podlators-2.5.1-3.el7.noarch                     @base
    Dep-Install perl-threads-1.87-4.el7.x86_64                        @base
    Dep-Install perl-threads-shared-1.43-6.el7.x86_64                 @base
    Dep-Install phonon-qt5-4.8.3-2.el7.x86_64                         @epel
    Dep-Install phonon-qt5-backend-gstreamer-4.8.2-2.el7.x86_64       @epel
    Dep-Install pinentry-qt-0.8.1-17.el7.x86_64                       @base
    Dep-Install pixman-0.34.0-1.el7.x86_64                            @base
    Dep-Install polkit-qt5-1-0.112.0-1.el7.x86_64                     @epel
    Dep-Install pulseaudio-libs-10.0-5.el7.x86_64                     @base
    Dep-Install pulseaudio-libs-glib2-10.0-5.el7.x86_64               @base
    Dep-Install qt3-3.3.8b-51.el7.x86_64                              @base
    Dep-Install qt5-qtbase-5.9.2-3.el7.x86_64                         @base
    Dep-Install qt5-qtbase-common-5.9.2-3.el7.noarch                  @base
    Dep-Install qt5-qtbase-gui-5.9.2-3.el7.x86_64                     @base
    Dep-Install qt5-qtdeclarative-5.9.2-1.el7.x86_64                  @base
    Dep-Install qt5-qtgraphicaleffects-5.9.2-1.el7.x86_64             @base
    Dep-Install qt5-qtquickcontrols-5.9.2-1.el7.x86_64                @base
    Dep-Install qt5-qtquickcontrols2-5.9.2-1.el7.x86_64               @base
    Dep-Install qt5-qtscript-5.9.2-1.el7.x86_64                       @base
    Dep-Install qt5-qtsvg-5.9.2-1.el7.x86_64                          @base
    Dep-Install qt5-qttools-common-5.9.2-1.el7.noarch                 @base
    Dep-Install qt5-qttools-libs-designer-5.9.2-1.el7.x86_64          @base
    Dep-Install qt5-qtx11extras-5.9.2-1.el7.x86_64                    @base
    Dep-Install qt5-qtxmlpatterns-5.9.2-1.el7.x86_64                  @base
    Dep-Install redhat-menus-12.0.2-8.el7.noarch                      @base
    Dep-Install sgml-common-0.6.3-39.el7.noarch                       @base
    Dep-Install speex-1.2-0.19.rc1.el7.x86_64                         @base
    Updated     systemd-219-57.el7.x86_64                             @anaconda
    Update              219-57.el7_5.1.x86_64                         @updates
    Updated     systemd-libs-219-57.el7.x86_64                        @anaconda
    Update                   219-57.el7_5.1.x86_64                    @updates
    Updated     systemd-sysv-219-57.el7.x86_64                        @anaconda
    Update                   219-57.el7_5.1.x86_64                    @updates
    Dep-Install taglib-1.8-7.20130218git.el7.x86_64                   @base
    Dep-Install trousers-0.3.14-2.el7.x86_64                          @base
    Dep-Install udisks2-2.7.3-6.el7.x86_64                            @base
    Dep-Install upower-0.99.4-2.el7.x86_64                            @base
    Dep-Install volume_key-libs-0.3.9-8.el7.x86_64                    @base
    Dep-Install wavpack-4.60.1-9.el7.x86_64                           @base
    Dep-Install xcb-util-0.4.0-2.el7.x86_64                           @base
    Dep-Install xcb-util-image-0.4.0-2.el7.x86_64                     @base
    Dep-Install xcb-util-keysyms-0.4.0-1.el7.x86_64                   @base
    Dep-Install xcb-util-renderutil-0.3.9-3.el7.x86_64                @base
    Dep-Install xcb-util-wm-0.4.1-5.el7.x86_64                        @base
    Dep-Install xdg-user-dirs-0.15-5.el7.x86_64                       @base
    Dep-Install xml-common-0.6.3-39.el7.noarch                        @base
history info
```

Answer (score -1):

not sure of that, but i think that kf5 is only framework basement for plasma. It is not kde-plasma 5 himself. 
Kde 5 is not yet available for centos 7.

Comment: Then why would the kde5 framework be on EPEL?